# Reporting Snapshot Run History - Failure Notification?

Tags: reporting, notification, analytic-snapshots

Our Reporting Snapshots fail intermittently on account of configuration changes that inadvertently violate their constraints (e.g., workflow on a target Object).

How might we notify our admins that a snapshot has failed? An email alert would be ideal but doesn't appear available, nor can I find Run History exposed in SOQL or any API. Is Reporting Snapshot Run History available anywhere from which a notification could be configured?

Comment: Any chance you can give a reproducible example of how to break one of these? I'm curious to experiment in a developer org.

Comment: Take any active Reporting Snapshot and delete a custom field that is mapped from the Source Report to the Target Object. No validation will prevent the deletion of the field. The next run of the Snapshot will have Result = Failed mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no way to access the results of a reporting snapshot run either in Apex or SOQL.

Reporting snapshots are represented as [`CronTrigger`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_crontrigger.htm) and [`CronJobDetail`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_cronjobdetail.htm) records, as Scheduled Apex is, with `CronJobDetail.JobType` equal to `'4'`. Neither object tracks the success or failure history of the scheduled job. The recorded last run date is the last run date, whether or not the last run failed.

When the reporting job fails, you get an email with a line like this:

> You can obtain further details by viewing the reporting snapshot's run detail page, or by clicking this link: https://MY_TRAILHEAD_ORG.salesforce.com/0A80b000000bXXX. If you are not currently logged into salesforce.com, you will be asked to do so to view the reporting snapshot's run detail page.

Interestingly, we do have an sObject there. The Id starting with `0A8` corresponds to an object called `ReportJobRun`. This object is undocumented and is not accessible other than through the reporting snapshot UI. It is not part of the global describe, and if described through Anonymous Apex returns no field information at all and shows `isAccessible = false`. You cannot query `ReportJobRun` or access it through the API.

While failed Scheduled Apex runs yield `AsyncApexJob` records that can be inspected, as far as I can tell reporting snapshot runs do not. I simulated a failure using your instructions and found no records of this kind. There's no `JobType` on [`AsyncApexJob`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm) for reporting runs, either, which supports the theory that they're not used for this purpose at all.

The only route I see would be to direct all reporting snapshot notifications to a redirect email service that would sniff the email content for errors and then forward successful runs to their intended recipients, or to manually inspect the run history in Setup. A shame.