# Trigger Report Snapshot Via Execute Anonymous

Tags: apex, snapshot

Has anybody tried executing reporting snapshots via execute anonymous. I only ask, because the "Preferred Start Times" that I have left via the Salesforce UI is now mid day. I would not want to take a snapshot of our teams pipeline mid day. These snapshots are best kept late at night.

Comment: edit or delete/read the snapshot schedule from the UI

Comment: @cropredy The UI is very limiting. That is why I want to see if I can Schedule the snapshots via executing Anonymous

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, if you want the snapshots to run late at night, and since they can only run once per day, why is the UI limiting?  That said, I'm don't know the specific answer to your question but I doubt this is possible; [semi-related answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/240541/reporting-snapshot-run-history-failure-notification)